# Does Git interfere with SVN?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Imagine I have a SVN repository. I can commit changes to it, when they are ready.

While I'm working on a particular task, I want to track my changes locally. So I thought that maybe I can just create a git repository inside the root of SVN repo.

Then I could do local commits to git and a "global commit" (check-in) to SVN when the work on a particular issue was finished.

Question: If I do it this way, can any problems arise on SVN side?

In theory, they shouldn't because Git will only create a `.git` directory in the root and that's it. But I want to hear about problems from people, who used this approach themselves.

Note: I want to have that Git locally, only for me (nobody else should even notice it). A company-wide migration to Git is out of question.

Comment: You should look into git-svn. Your usage of git won't be invisible but you get most of the benefits of git while being fully compatible with SVN. That should work well enough until you find another company that embraces git fully. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issue, provided that:

- you consider the fact your git commits won't be in sync with the SVN checkins.
- you make sure that SVN ignores the `.git` folder (with an ignore property)
- you make sure git is ignoring SVN metadata (at least the `.svn` folder)